# TimThumb: An error occured fetching image

Tags: wordpress, timthumb

I'm trying to create a new item in uSquare, but when i insert an image I only see a break image icon and invastigating about the issue I found this

```
A TimThumb error has occured

The following error(s) occured:
An error occured fetching image.


Query String : src=http://eryagame.altervista.org/blog/blog_eng/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Fotostupida.jpg&w=180&h=125
TimThumb version : 2.8.10
```

I tried to figure out what the problem is but can not find it...

Answer (score 0):

Simply, your image doesn't exist ( http://eryagame.altervista.org/blog/blog_eng/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Fotostupida.jpg ).

I also suggest you to upgrade to the latest timthumb version 2.8.13 ( http://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php )

Answer (score 0):

For WP sites using domain mapping in subdomain mode, simply open timthumb.php and change line 215

FROM:

```
$this->myHost = preg_replace('/^www\./i', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

TO:

```
$this->myHost = preg_replace('/^www\./i', '', 'yoursubdomain.yourwordpressmultisite.com');
```